# Why is .gitignore not tracking a file despite using the ! notation

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have the following in my .gitignore:

```
data/
!data/data_file.csv
```

yet the data_file.csv is not being tracked and I get the following when I check the ignore rules:

```
 git check-ignore -v data/data_file.csv  
.gitignore:2:data/      data/data_file.csv
```

I have tried

```
git rm -r -f --cached .
git add -A
git commit -m "Some commit message"
```

Can anyone explain why this is and ho to get the file to be tracked?

Comment: Once you ignore a directory, then it is impossible to unignore something in it. You could attempt `data/*` instead of `data/`, because then you do not ignore the directory, but all of its contents. There are plenty of questions on SO that deal with this conundrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to ignore the entire folder, merely its contents.
That will allow you to un-ignore the content item(s) of your choice.

```
data/*
!data/data_file.csv
```

Comment: In this particular case leading slashes are not needed. A leading slash is recommended in the case `/data/` but `/data/*` and `data/*` are equivalent. The same is for `!/data/data_file.csv` and `!data/data_file.csv` — they're equivalent. See the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format : "*If there is **a separator** at the beginning or **middle (or both)** of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself.*" — emphasize mine.